# PHP. How to store empty arrays in ini files if you parse them with function parse_ini_string()?

Tags: php, ini

For example I tried so:

```
parse_ini_string('
    abc[] =
');
```

but the element abc is not empty, there is 1 empty string in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't store *empty* arrays in an INI file directly. The INI format is not expressive enough - the syntax above describes an array push, and as such it pushes an empty element onto the array.

A workaround, albeit ugly, is something like this:

```
$parsed = parse_ini_file('file.ini');

foreach ($parsed as $k => &$v) {
  if ($v === array('')) {
    $v = array();
  }
}
```